# Export billing file - lack of permission as a owner

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm owner of the project as well billing account at Google Cloud Platform, I would like to export detail billing to a file but I get:

> "You don’t have permission to update this bucket"

When I hit `Billing->Billing Export->File Export` and `"Enable billing export"` (naming and JSON/CSV - doesn't matter).

What I'm missing there? Is there some special permission that owner by default doesn't have? On the other hand I can enable billing export to BigQuery.

Comment: It looks weird, can you try it in the Incognito mode to see if it works?

Comment: Thanks for suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, on incognito mode I got instead that message "The bucket you specified does not exist" which was pretty straight forward from that point, thanks @JL-HN !
I had to create bucket on Google Storage, and provide it to export files for billing purposes.